# Consequences of projecting in different resolution rasters

Tags: raster, r, resolution, modelling

I have used 2.5 resolution enviromental rasters to build a model using ENMeval. Which are the consequences of projecting (ENMeval::maxnet.predictRaster function) a choosen model in the same area in a different time using rasters with a finer resoltion (0.5)?

Comment: You've got that the wrong way around, you should resample your 0.5 to 2.5 instead of resampling your 2.5 to 0.5 as the output can only ever be as accurate as your least accurate data source so as such you must make your 'good' resolution rasters the same as your 'bad' rasters.. and then the overall accuracy is the sum of both rasters inaccuracies unless you sub-pixel shift to known accurate data then your RMSE can be calculated against the inaccuracy of the hook point data.

Comment: So, the consequence is only related to statistic error, right? This, hypothetical, If I dont do the resample and go ahead and project using 0.5 I will get the same prediction area (in a large scale) than if I use 2.5?

Comment: You will only get a false confidence in your data if you do it that way. You can't create information that isn't there but looking at your data with a finer resolution it would seem to be better but isn't.